# Identifying this type of pin header soldered to the board

Tags: pcb, identification, pins

Does anyone know what these are called?

[image: image showing pins fitted to a PCB]

Comment: I don't think there's anything more specific than just calling them "pins".

Comment: I am trying to make a humidity sensor and a lot of people out there have used it. If this many people have used it I am pretty sure its not custom made.  
 https://shop.bb-sensors.com/en/Measurement-by-branches/Building-automation/Electrolytic-humidity-sensor-EFS-10.html

Comment: The drawing looks to be in error when it claims 1.27 mm for a *double* pin spacing, that's inconsistent with the overall width of 5.08 mm.  But 1.27 mm for a single spacing (eg twice the density of traditional 100 mil headers) might be likely.

Comment: almost looks like a USB connector without the shell

Comment: @ChrisStratton That's not pointing at double pin spacing, it's a single pin spacing dimension next to a pin width dimension, it's just some of the lines involved are extremely faint.

Answer (score 3):

That type of pin was (and perhaps still is) called "SIP pin". They were available in different lengths, and made to fit different PCB thicknesses.

You will still find some little breakout boards with those fitted (for example, from [Capital Advanced Technologies Inc.](https://www.capitaladvanced.com/) - I don't have any connection with the company) but as you know, nowadays the square header pins are more common on breakout boards.

Those SIP pins could also be used to convert early SIMM memory modules, into (now obsolete) SIPP memory modules. More about that (and some photos) at: [Wikipedia - SIPP memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIPP_memory).

I actually found a datasheet for the SIP pins used by the above company on another website, but couldn't find it on their own website (at least, not any more). So here is the 1 page datasheet:

[image: Datasheet for SIP pin SP-1A from Capital Advanced Technologies Inc.]

<sub>Image source: [Manualzz](https://manualzz.com/doc/7948572/pin-sp-1a-dwg)</sub>

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: @Neil - You're welcome :-)  As explained in the help centre [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) you can "accept" an answer (which adds a green tick), if it has solved your problem. That removes the question from the unanswered list.

Comment: Still available from Farnell/Newark: https://www.newark.com/amp-te-connectivity/1544425-2/frame-lead-sil-2-54mm/dp/28T0237 and maybe others.

Answer (score 0):

the pins are  rectangular 0.4 by o.25mm so 0.6mm holes seems like a good size.

create a footprint with a line of 4 holes of 0.6mm diameter with 1.27mm spacing between centers, you'll probably want to use oval pads.

Comment: Thank you so much